# MKMarkerAnnotationView cluster color

Tags: mapkit, ios11, mapkitannotation

I’ve been trying out the new iOS 11 MKMarkerAnnotationView, and finally clustering works like a charm. But the problem is that the clusters have the wrong color as you can see in the picture. How can I control this? [image: Wrong cluster color]

Answer (score 13):

Nevermind I managed to figure it out.

I added the following to the `mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation)` function of the delegate.

```
if let cluster = annotation as? MKClusterAnnotation {
    let markerAnnotationView = MKMarkerAnnotationView()
    markerAnnotationView.glyphText = String(cluster.memberAnnotations.count)
    markerAnnotationView.markerTintColor = UIColor.appPrimary
    markerAnnotationView.canShowCallout = false

    return markerAnnotationView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are not using `MKMapViewDelegate` you can just set, in your `MKMarkerAnnotationView` subclass,

```
clusteringIdentifier = MKMapViewDefaultClusterAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier
```

and in your view controller

```
mapView.register(SubclassMarkerView.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier)

mapView.register(SubclassMarkerView.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultClusterAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier)
```